# Mass of a body with a mass density function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $T$ be the body consisting of the points $(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3$ that satisfies the following inequality

$$0<\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}<1-|z| $$
Compute the mass of $T$ with the density function $\delta (x,y,z)=(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{-\frac{3}{4}}$

I essentially began by converting stuff into cylindrical-coordinates such that $x^2+y^2=r^2$. We should also have that since $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}<1-|z| \Rightarrow r<\sqrt{1-2z}$

So I came up with the triple integral

$$M=2\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\sqrt{1-2z}} (r^2+z^2)^{-\frac{3}{4}}rdrdzd\theta $$

But when we arrive at the integrating with respect to $z$ part, it's a really disgusting integral. I'm thinking that spherical coordinates might be a better idea, but I can't seem to figure the integration boundraries, so if someone could helå me out, that would be grand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing Your effort:

$$
\begin{aligned}
2\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}{\int_{r=0}^{r=\sqrt{1-2z}}{(r^{2}+z^{2})^{-\frac{3}{4}}}\pi dr^{2}}dz&=8\pi\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}{\left(\sqrt{1-z}-\sqrt{z}\right)\ }dz\\
\\
&=\frac{16\pi}{3}\left(1-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Wait, how do you arrive at $dr^2$?. Whenever I solve the first integral I just get $2(\sqrt[4]{z^2-2z+1}-\sqrt[4]{z^2}) $, and whenever I try integrating that wrt $z$, whelp it's ugly.

Comment: @DerpyMcDerp notice that $\sqrt[4]{1-2z+z^{2}}=\sqrt{1-z}$ and $\sqrt[4]{z^{2}}=\sqrt{z}$ in our boundary of integration

Comment: This may come off as a stupid question, but why? I don't see it immediately.

Comment: @DerpyMcDerp $1-2z+z^{2}=(1-z)^{2}$ and in our boundary of integration, $1-z$ and $z$ are both non - negative.

Comment: Thanks, my morning coffee hasn't really kicked in yet and this helped a lot!